# xdotool typing wrong sequence

Tags: automation, xdotools

when I type let's say

```sh
xdotool type --delay 1000 'hello/@Bey-hapi['
```

I get:

```
hello&2Bey/hapi8
```

I don't use a us keyboard layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I managed to set the keyboard layout to spanish by `setxkbmap es`. That solves the issue